# How to Manage Geo Cty for Indian User in AMP

Tags: amp-html, geo

I am developing a feature for showing data on the basis of Indian City but didn't find the soution in AMP. I am referring below document as example document
https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/personalization/geolocation_with_amp-list/

Comment: https://blog.amp.dev/2018/05/03/dynamic-geo-personalization/

Comment: https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-geo/?format=websites

Comment: https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/user-consent/geolocation-based_consent_flow/